# cmd_vel topic from navigation stage not sending to raspberry robot

Tags: ros, navigation, communication, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I have some problem with navigation stage module. I have a robot with raspberry pi and hokuyo lidar mount on it and base station for mapping calculation.
The standard way to run the ROS on two machine is: 1. start roscore 2. start scan streaming 3. start reading cmd_vel on robot 4. start tf publisher 5. start rf2o 6. start hector_slam 7. start navigation_stage 8. start frontier_exploration
And my problem is when I try to set 2d Nav point somewhere in the room and in the same team run echo on cmd_vel topic I can see that navigation stage is publishing some velocity data. But when I run cmd_vel echo on RPi there is no data.
The more interesting thing is that I wrote my manual control topic which is publishing to cmd_vel and this is working correctly and robot is moving.
It seems that for some reason when  running navigation_stage data is only visible on local PC and not on RPi.
Can you help finding solution for that problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289370/cmd_vel-topic-from-navigation-stage-not-sending-to-raspberry-robot/) by [bjurek5](https://answers.ros.org/users/34775/bjurek5/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @Rodolfo8 said it's probably a networking configuration problem. You have to make sure you've correctly configured the `ROS_MASTER_URI` variable from your PC and Raspberry.
Try `echo $ROS_MASTER_URI` from your PC and from the Raspberry. Do it from every terminal you are using to be sure they all share the same master.

Another thing is that by default you should have `ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311/` or something similar, but you should change it to `http://192.168.1.XX:11311/` (the IP adress of the raspberry or the PC) and then run `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.XX:11311/` from all your terminals.

Finally, you should also set the variable `ROS_HOSTNAME` to the corresponding IP adress.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-23**:\

> set the variable `ROS_HOSTNAME` to the corresponding IP adress.

I'd recommend sticking to hostnames for `ROS_HOSTNAME`, and use `ROS_IP` for IPs.

The former can exploit the flexibility that DNS provides (but you need a working DNS).

**Comment by [bjurek5](https://answers.ros.org/users/34775/bjurek5/) on 2018-04-23**:
I will check in afternoon where I have configured IP's and where not. Does the console running roscore also need to have configured  `ROS_MASTER_URI` before ?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-04-23**:
Yes, every console must have the same `ROS_MASTER_URI`

**Comment by [bjurek5](https://answers.ros.org/users/34775/bjurek5/) on 2018-05-07**:
I added on host PC export ROS_MASTER_URI to .bashrc file, and the second thing where I had problem earlier was to have in virtualbox configuration only one bridged network card, for some reason I had two activated, after disabling everything runs well, thanks for support